# Easy way to create a set of "fake" web services

Tags: javascript, html, web-services

I want to become better at making client side html/javascript apps.  JSbin.com is a great site for that.  But I want to have my test sites also call web services to fetch data.   The data can be completely fake, I just need something to interact with.

Is there a good way to make a publicly available set of web services with your own fake data?  It can be temporary, that's fine.  But it cannot be something that runs only on my local machine, as I want to be able to test this and work with it while, for example, far away from my desk working on my ipad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsFiddle has an `echo` feature that allows you to simulate XHR requests.  It supports JSON, XML, jsonP, etc.

From their [docs](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html)

```
new Request.JSON({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {
        json: JSON.encode({
            text: 'some text',
            array: [1, 2, 'three'],
            object: {
                par1: 'another text',
                par2: [3, 2, 'one'],
                par3: {}
            }
        }),
        delay: 3
    },
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        show_response(response, $('post'));
    }
}).send();

show_response = function(obj, result) {
    $H(obj).each(function(v, k) {
        new Element('li', {
            text: k + ': ' + v
        }).inject(result);
    });
    result.highlight();
};
```

Comment: It looks like jsFiddle is a good place to do this. I can make some fake data and put it onto gitHub, then get that from jsFiddle using echo.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, just brainstorming here because I'm not completely certain I follow what you're trying to do.  Could you set up your own web server in your home or office and expose your web services there?  You may have to call it by the IP address of your modem/router, and have port-forwarding turned on to get to the machine hosting your web service, but theoretically you should be able to do that.

Have I missed what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to avoid setting up my own server for this.  Want it completely independent of all that.  This is only for testing as a side project.